# What is the batch script equivalent for the following OS X batch script iterating installed fonts?

Tags: windows, macos, batch-file, cmd

I am trying to make use the answer given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148228/19356). What is the batch script equivalent for the following OS X batch script iterating installed fonts?

```
for F in /Library/Fonts/*.ttf
do
   FONT=`basename "$F" .ttf`
   xelatex "\def\myfont{$FONT}\input{handout.tex}"
   mv handout.pdf "$FONT".pdf
done
```

Comment: Have you tried starting out by using Google to find examples of Batch For loops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excluding xelatex, that is not part of the base OS, the rest of the script could be

```
for %%f in ("%systemroot%\Fonts\*.ttf") do (
    echo full path to file          : %%~ff
    echo name and extension of file : %%~nxf
    echo only name of file          : %%~nf

    rem xelatex "\def\myfont{%%~nf}\input{handout.tex}"
    rem move handout.pdf "%%~nf.pdf"
)
```